# Anyway of clearing text in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle, cls

Is there anyway of clearing text in IDLE, its really anoying when i run the script a couple of times and then there's a cluster of words which is really hard to read.

and yes I have looked on google, stack_overflow and a couple of more websites but i cant find anything useful.

I tried to do:

```
import os
def cls():
    os.system("cls")
>>>cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using the actual IDLE shell, I don't think there's any way to do it. IDLE is not meant to run programs from, it's just supposed to be a development tool. If you want to run programs from terminal or cmd, you can clear the text easily.

Use this instead:

```
os.system("clear") # or "cls" on windows
```

or

```
subprocess.call('clear') # or "cls" on windows
```

To fake it in IDLE, you can use something like:

```
print("\n" * 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import call as c

def cls():

    c("cls",shell=True)

print([x for x in range(10000)])

cls()
```

Whenever you wish to clear console call the function cls, but note that this function will clear the screen in Windows only if you are running Python Script using **cmd prompt**, it will not clear the buffer if you running by IDLE.